# How to extract only the values from a map

Tags: scala

I have the following Map after doing a groupBy and then partition/sliding on an List of Lists. Now i'm only interested in the values of the map, the keys are irrelevant. Basically i'm trying to extract the subset of Lists after groupBy and sliding/partition and perform additional map and reduce functions on them.

```
var sectionMap : Map[Int,List[List[Any]]] = Map(
  1 -> List(List(1,20,"A"), List(1,40,"B")),
  2 -> List(List(2,30,"A"), List(2,80,"F")),
  3 -> List(List(3,80,"B"))
)
```

I used `sectionMap.values` but it returned a format like `Iterable[List[List[Any]]]` However I want the following type `List[List[Any]]`. Is there is one step function to apply to achieve the result?

```
  List(
   List(1,20,"A"),
   List(1,40,"B"),
   List(2,30,"A"),
   List(2,80,"F"),
   List(3,80,"B")
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sectionMap.values.flatten.toList`.

`flatten` convert types like `Seq[Seq[T]]` to `Seq[T]` and `toList` convert `Iterable` to `List`

Answer (score 1):

you need to do map.values which will gives you the List of values. As values are List of List you will get `Iterable(List(List(1,20,"A"))) :Iterable[List[List[Any]]]` like this so you can do flatten to make it `Iterable(List(1,20,"A")): Iterable[List[Any]]`.
If  you want it to be `List[List[Any]]` do .toList after flatten.

you can use:

```
sectionMap.values.flatten

//output List(List(1, 20, A), List(1, 40, B), List(2, 30, A), List(2, 80, F), List(3, 80, B))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` or `flatMap` or  `collect` method on sectionMap as below:

```
sectionMap.map(_._2).flatten.toList
sectionMap.flatMap(_._2).toList

sectionMap.collect{case (x,y) => y}.flatten.toList
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use flatMap:

```
sectionMap.flatMap{ case (_, x) => x }.toList
```

It combines flattening and extraction into the same iteration.